# Filtering Mutual Relation in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, People and Relation. There schemas are as follows:

```
People(id int primary key, name varchar(10))
Relation(id1 references People(id), id2 references People(id), r varchar(10))
```

Here, `r` in relation can represent `'partner'` or `'rival'`.

My task is to filter the mutual relationship from schemas into a separate table  where they consider each other as partners or rivals. Here, mutual relationship is where both people consider each other as `'partner'` or `'rival'`. For example, `1, 2, friend` and `2, 1, friend` is a mutual relationship pair `1, 2`.

I attempted to join the table, but unable to filter out the mutual relationship pair. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
with relations(people_1,people_2,rel_type) as
(
  select 1,2,'friend' union all
  select 2,1,'friend' union all
  select 3,4,'enemy'
)
select r.people_1,r.people_2,r.rel_type,
  r2.people_1,r2.people_2,r2.rel_type
from relations as r
join relations as r2 on r.people_1=r2.people_2 and r.people_2=r2.people_1
```

May be something like this can be helpful